# how to start first thread complete to after second thread start

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety

Am using some method i need to some method complete to start to another method so that am using thread function, How to start one thread follow by to second thread start?

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                loadIrrigationSourceMaster();
                loadIrrigationMaster();
                loadSeasonMaster();
                loadFactoryMaseter();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread1.start();

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                loadTransport();
                plantTypeMaster();
                plotOwnerTypeMaster();
                ExitRatoonMaster();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread2.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  (new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //TODO: fist thread code here 
            Log.w("tag","1");
            (new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                       //TODO: second thread code here 
                        Log.w("tag","2");
                }
            })).start();
        }
    })).start();
```

out put of above:

```
tag:1
tag:2
```

but i dont think it's a good idea . just put rest of your job in first `Thread`

Comment: but its call the all the method at same time , i need to complete to after start the another method

Comment: it will run method/code above second thread. then it will get to second thread `start()` method to run it .i edited the answer .

Comment: do you have used any `thread` in those method in first thread?. if yes , then thats why it's jumps to second thread before it finish the job .

Comment: output ok , but button to click same time output call the all the method. need to first tag complete all method to another tag will start.

Comment: first thread calling the some for loop condition based on the another method so that am using first thread complete to start with second thread

Comment: private void loadFactoryMaseter() {
        
                mSeas = AppUtils.getSeasonMaster();
                for (SeasonMasterDB s : mSeas) {
                    listString += s.name + "\t".replace("\t", ",").replaceAll(",", ",");
                }
                if (listString.endsWith(",")) {
                    listString = listString.substring(0, listString.length() - 1);
                    words = listString.split(",");
                }
    }

Comment: please edit your question and post related code to these methods : `  loadIrrigationSourceMaster();
                loadIrrigationMaster();
                loadSeasonMaster();
                loadFactoryMaseter();`

Comment: i edit the question sir, once complete the loadfactoryMaster(); after calling the  loadTransport();

Comment: no, post the code inside the method . what code is all those methods ?

Comment: Can you please your Email id sir , i send the full code

Answer (score 0):

To wait for a thread to complete its execution before moving on, you can use the `join()` method: [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join())

Specifically for your problem, you can put `thread1.join()`, right after the `thread1.start()` call. The join call will block the calling thread until `thread1` is finished with its execution, so that `thread2` will be initialized and executed after `thread1` is finished.

Alternatively, you can also call `thread1.join()` in the beginning of the `run()` method of `thread2`, so that the main thread won't need to be blocked by the `join()` call.

Comment: how .? can you please edit code explain the briefly please